# Is there a way to retrieve the url from the webbrowser search bar?

Tags: python, automation

For example, if I enter in the search bar: "https://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=tacobell", the url changes to "https://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=tacobell&find_loc=Fort+Worth%2C+TX". I'm wondering is their a way to grab that url with python. [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xYplb.png)

Answer (score 1):

yes try

```py
browser.current_url
```

```
url = "https://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=tacobell"
browser.get(url)
print(browser.current_url)
```

prints -

```
https://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=tacobell&find_loc=San+Francisco%2C+CA
```